# Accessing Object Properties (3rd level) of a Model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Below is a very simple app which takes the model object from controllers and shows using handle bars. I am unable to access properties that is nested inside a property like `{{foobar.foo.bar}}`.

### JavaScript

```
app = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: '#foo'
});

app.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        controller.set('foobar', foobar);
    }
});

foobar = {
     name: 'item name',
     foo: {
         bar: 'value',
         id: 1
     }
};
```

### HTML/Handlebars

```
<div id="foo">
    <p>Name: {{foobar.name}}</p>
    <p>Name: {{foobar.foo.bar}}</p>
</div>
```

`{{foobar.name}}` works while `{{foobar.foo.bar}}` does not. Any ideas?

Comment: What does `{{foobar.foo}}` emit?

Comment: If my answer helps you, plz do validate it as the correct one. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks alright to me. I tried in in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sephy/o201hmkn/) (you can play with it if you like) and everything's fine. You might have mispell a property or something like that.
Is it your real code or a simplification for StackOverflow purpose ?
In any case, for this kind of situation, I strongly encourage you to install the [Emberjs Inspector Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi), which will help you target your issue by taking a look at each property.

**Template :**

```
<h2>Ember.js DEMO</h2>
<script id="index" type="text/x-handlebars">
    INTERNAL : <br/>
    {{foobar}} <br/>
    {{foobar.name}} <br/>
    {{foobar.foo}} <br/>
    {{foobar.foo.bar}} <br/>
    {{foobar.foo.id}} <br/><br/>

    EXTERNAL : <br/>
    {{foobarExt}} <br/>
    {{foobarExt.name}} <br/>
    {{foobarExt.foo}} <br/>
    {{foobarExt.foo.bar}} <br/>
    {{foobarExt.foo.id}} <br/>
</script>
```

**Javascript :**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {
    // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        controller.set('foobar', {
             name: 'item name',
             foo: {
                 bar: 'value',
                 id: 1
             }
        });

        controller.set('foobarExt', externalfoobar);
    }
});

var externalfoobar = {
    name: 'item name',
    foo: {
        bar: 'value',
        id: 1
    }
};
```